# CGPoints of a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cgpoint

How do we get all four coordinates of a UIView? I thought this would be it.

```
CGPoint viewOriginX = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.frame.origin fromView:nil];
```

But what about CGPoint of the top right, bottom left and bottom right points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = [self.view frame];
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame));
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame));
CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
```

If you need those coordinates in a particular view, the first line should be something like

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:[self.view bounds] toView:someOtherView];
```

Comment: Calling `convertRect:toView:` with a view's `frame` doesn't really make a lot of sense because the frame is relative to the *superview's* coordinate system. You'd typically use the `bounds` or call the method on the superview.